# Supress #f in Visual Studio from opening "Feedback Hub"

Tags: autohotkey

I have the following autohotkey script:

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2

#f::
if WinExist("Mozilla Firefox")
    WinActivate
    return
#v::
if WinExist("Microsoft Visual Studio")
    WinActivate
    return
```

#f shortcut should focus Firefox and #v shortcut should focus VS. And it works except when my VS window is in focus and I press #f to switch to Firefox. Instead of switching to Firefox, #f shortcut launches Feedback Hub.

I don't want that.

How can fix this problem?

Comment: I suggest not using the Windows key for your own shortcuts. As an alternative in this case, you could pin the applications to the task bar and then use Win+1, Win+2 and so on to start/activate them.

Comment: @DanielB That suggestion is not going to work for me well. Doing Win+# is very strenuous for my wrist/fingers, in addition to having non-intuitive shortcut. Since I work as web developer and already have many shortcuts occupying ctrl, shift and alt keys (and their combinations) in VS and Firefox (with Vimium extension) using win key is almost the only option I have left.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that VS was running with elevated privileges but ahk script was not. To make above script work run complied ahk script with elevated privileges.

After farther research I found out that technically this question is a duplicate of this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890351/why-is-visual-studio-catching-key-events-before-autohotkey